# InfluxDB Queries for JMeter data

Tags: jmeter, influxdb, grafana

I am trying to build the InfluxDB + Grafana + JMeter dashboard. 
I am using InfluxDB 0.10, Grafana 2.6 and JMeter 2.13.

[Backend Listener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1QuO.png)

My backend Listener looks good. I have listed a few names in the Sampler's List.

When I try to create graphs for the Sampler's I am unable to.

I also tried the Grafana Dashboard Generator, but still unable to create graphs for the individual Sampler's.

Any suggestions.

Comment: does influxdb have data from jmeter?

Comment: If InfluxDB holds the jmeter data, can you share the schema?

Answer (score 0):

First check if Jmeter is shipping data in InfluxDB by running DB commands.